# Django and JSON

Tags: python, django, json, dojo

I'm looking to create the following JSON in Django (I'm working with a [`DataGrid`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojox/grid/example_grid_styling_rows.html)):

```
{
    identifier: 'id',
    label: 'name',
    items: [
            { id: 'AF', name:'Africa', type:'continent', population:'900 million', area: '30,221,532 sq km',
                    timezone: '-1 UTC to +4 UTC',
                    children:[{_reference:'EG'}, {_reference:'KE'}, {_reference:'SD'}] },
                { id: 'EG', name:'Egypt', type:'country' },
                { id: 'BR', name:'Brazil', type:'country', population:'186 million' },
                { id: 'AR', name:'Argentina', type:'country', population:'40 million' }
]}
```

I'm doing something like this at the moment:

```
filesJson = []
for index,lv in enumerate(letterList):
    printed = ''
    if lv.letter.received:
        inout = '<span class="..."></span>'
    else:
        inout = '<span class="..."></span>'
    if lv.printed_last:
        printed = '<span class="..."></span>'
    filesJson.append({'id':str(index),
                      'letterID':lv.letter.id,
                      'position':str(index).zfill(4),
                      'inout':inout,
                      'dateH':lv.humanReadableCreated(),
                      'date':lv.created.strftime('%d/%m/%y'),
                      'time':lv.created.strftime('%H:%M'),
                      'user':lv.created_by.username,
                      'name':lv.name(),
                      'printed':printed})

finalJson = {}
finalJson['id'] = 'id'
finalJson['label'] = 'name'
finalJson['items'] = filesJson
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(finalJson), mimetype="application/json")
```

I keep getting `list indices must be integers, not str`. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that your example is not actually valid JSON: you must use double quotes for both keys and values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a typo...

```
finalJson = []
```

Should be

```
finalJson = {}
```

Comment: I have corrected my question

Comment: You were right. It all works now :)